# scrollHeight and offsetheight give value of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I console `offset` and `scrollheight` it return undefined and I don't know why

```js
var element = angular.element(
  document.querySelector("#div-content")
);
console.log(element.scrollHeight);
console.log(element.offsetHeight);
vm.hasVerticalScrollbar =
  element.scrollHeight != element.offsetHeight;

if (vm.hasVerticalScrollbar) {
  console.log("true");
} else {
  console.log("false");
}
```

```html
<div id="div-content">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I want to know if the dive has scrollbar or not but the first step `(scrollHeight & offsetHeight)` doesn't work.
I don't want to use jQuery

Comment: Use `element[0].scrollHeight` and `element[0].offsetHeight`

Comment: Please see the below link for the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-zc2fxq?file=home%2Fhome.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `var element = document.querySelector("#div-content")` directly, rather than use `angular.element(...)` wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of this:

```
document.querySelector
```

You can use angular.element like this:

```
var element = angular.element("#div-content");
```

To get scrollHeight/offsetHeight try:

```
let scrollHeight = element[0].scrollHeight;
let offsetHeight = element[0].offsetHeight;
```